# Is $page only an array important for theming purposes?

Tags: theming

I know Wordpress theming, but I am a beginner with Drupal theming. Drupal render array totally confuses me.

1. Do all modules put their content in the `$page` array?
2. Is `$page` only an array that is important for theming purpose? If the answer is no, then what kind of renderable arrays are available in Drupal for advanced theming?

Answer (score 3):

There is just a type of render array, and it is the one described in [drupal_render()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_render/7); the form API extends the render array with properties necessary to validate/submit a form element. The purpose of a render array is just to theme elements present in a page; it is not used for other purposes, if not rendering/theming.

The output of a module is always part of a render array, except when a module implements code similar to the following one.

```
  function mymodule_menu() {
    $items['abc/def'] = array(
      'page callback' => 'mymodule_abc_view',
    );
    return $items;
  }

  function mymodule_abc_view() {
    echo "<html><head><title>Error</title></head><body><span>Error page</span></body></html>";
    drupal_exit();
  }
```

If you visit http://example.com/abc/def, there isn't any render array involved in rendering the page.

Comment: sir thanks for your reply and  editing. but sir i am still confuse. can you please explain answer in simple word and with theming example. i understand nothing regarding answer to my first quertion(Do all modules put their content in the $page array?)

Comment: Do all modules put their content in the `$page` array? Yes, except in one case. Is $page only an array that is important for theming purpose? The render array is used only for theming, so yes.